# Ubercart USPS shipping module package options

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, ubercart, usps

There is a client we are assisting with an Ubercart installation and they are having issues with the packages that are used for USPS, in addition it seems that the shipping costs are way off in the cart.  I have looked at the USPS documentation for Ubercart and it seems really poor especially in how it is working. Has anyone had any experience with this or maybe has some idea for fine tuning the module/API.

#### One Simple sample issue

I would like to add some available packages into the admin under the shipping settings, under the USPS product description there are only a couple of the full options for USPS packages available. I would like to add some packages into this field.  How is this controlled?

Comment: The documentation is very poor, definitely. Could you describe the issues you're having in a bit more detail? With regards the shipping costs being off, in what way are they off (can you see a pattern for example?)

Comment: @Clive - Thank you for the reply.  I have added a sample issue above, there are many others but this would be one I would like to work out first then test around this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems USPS breaks the types of shipping option down into Envelope, Parcel, Intl. Envelope and Intl. Parcel. These are hard-coded into the module in the `uc_usps_shipping_method()` function.

From there, each of these shipping types has a further set of options which can be configured at `admin/store/settings/quotes/methods/usps`, in the collapsed fieldsets you'll find a long list of the potential options that can be offered to the customer (`U.S.P.S. First-Class Mail Postcard` etc.); I'd imagine these are more inline with the large set of options the US Postal Service probably provides, and probably the options you're looking for.

As far as adding new ones goes though, you'd have to do this programmatically as the afore-mentioned options are again hard-coded into the USPS module (look for the last 4 functions in the module file). I'm not entirely sure how you'd go about doing this though as I can't find a `hook_shipping_method_alter()` function anywhere in Ubercart's docs.

Hope that helps a bit at least

Comment: Thank you @Clive - this seems like really good info and at the very least a lead on the main issue at hand.  Will be looking into this soon and will report back with results.